# Elasticsearch response into Firebase (Flashlight)

Tags: elasticsearch, firebase

I am trying to set up the [Flashlight example](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/tree/master/example) for Firebase (first locally) but got stuck. I manage to push the search to Firebase:

[image]

But **I do not get a response post into Firebase**. My app.js logs say

`Connected to ElasticSearch host localhost:9200
Connecting to Firebase https://my-instance.firebaseio.com
Indexing firebase/message using path "Posts"
Queue started, IN: "search/request", OUT: "search/response"`

... and is updating me about the constantly updating index based on Firebase activity.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a quick check, where it says `my-instance` in your logging output, you have the actual name of your Firebase database?

Comment: correct, it does my actual Firebase name. The pushing of search queries works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by changing the following in the config.js file:

Instead of a basic *FB_URL Path* and a specific *exports.paths* I had to have a specific *FB_URL Path*.
This works:

```
exports.FB_URL   = 'https://my-instance.firebaseio.com/gmail-com';
exports.paths = [
   {
      path:  "Posts",
      index: "firebase",
      type:  "message",
   }
];
```

This does not:

```
exports.FB_URL   = 'https://my-instance.firebaseio.com';
exports.paths = [
   {
      path:  "gmail-com/Posts",
      index: "firebase",
      type:  "message",
   }
];
```

Not sure why...